# How to include top comment per each post as a separate collection in meteor?

Tags: meteor

If I have a collection of posts when entering a view of a posts collection, and each of these posts has a collection of comments on them, how could I list the top comment for each post along side of them?

E.g:

```
  this.route('postsList', {
    path: '/:posts',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('posts');
    },
    data: function() {
      return Posts.find({});
    }
  });
```

And then I'm iterating through the collection of posts on a page.

```
{{#each posts}}
  {{> postItem}}
{{/each}}

<template name="postItem">
  {{title}}
  {{topComment}}
</template>
```

I'd like to put the top comment for each post item.

How can I do this with my templates/subscriptions/publications?

Posts and comments are separate collections.

If it were an embedded collection I could see the ease of use but how to deal with separate collections?

If I published a recent comment type of publication how could I subscribe to it for each post as the most recent one? Or am I thinking the wrong way here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insist on having two totally separated collections, you would get into problems with efficient database queries. What you could do is to have something like `recentComment` field in your posts collection. Should this field point to `id` of the most recent comment related to the given post, you could alter your `posts` subscription to include the recent comments as well:

```
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  var listOfIds = _.pluck(Posts.find({}, {fields: recentComment}).fetch(), 'recentComment');
  return [
    Posts.find(),
    Comments.find({_id:{$in:listOfIds}})
  ];
});
```

Note that this solution is not fully reactive but it's good enough in most cases.